# PyInstaller Convert to macOS

Tags: python, macos, cross-platform, pyinstaller

I wrote some python code for a friend of mine and used pyinstall to package it up for him.  The problem is I use windows and he uses a Mac. Is there anyway I can convert my script to run on his computer? Or is he going to need to install python himself?  How do people with two different OSes usually work together?

Comment: Do you mean macOS instead of iOS? Good luck finding a way to run a python program on an iPhone.

Comment: yes macOS, sorry, shows how much I know about apple OS's ;)

Comment: Short answer, Yes.  A Mac can run Python.

Comment: But how can I get it to run a .exe file I made on windows using pyinstaller? Is there a way to convert it to a .exe a mac can run, or do i need  to write the script on a mac then convert it to the .exe using pyinstaller on a mac?

Comment: Why do you need to make an .exe?  What is wrong with just using the script?

Comment: Without trying to bore you with the details, I tried to help him download Python3.6 over the phone but all these issues kept popping up, and my limited windows touble-shooting tactics  didn't work, so I decided I'd just zip it up with pyinstall which is what I do when I write little scrips for my co-workers.

Comment: I've since tried uploading it to pythonAnywhere, but that's had it's own issues involving Firefox() webdriver, and so that would be a separate question.

Answer (score 2):

I found your question while solving this issue.
The sad thing is you will need a mac to build the program for the mac os.
I took a while doing this as my program was a bit bulky but in the end, the hustle is worth it.

Some of the issues you might face regarding pyinstaller can be addressed on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56386290/6528502).

Comment: Thanks, now I own a mac, and a pc, solved my problems haha.

Comment: haha sorry you had to buy, one cant even build a private vps with mac without mac hardware for this things @Mwspencer. you can consider upvoting and - or accepting it as a solution